# Edit Text in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, xml, command-line, console-application

I wrote this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContactManagement
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
FileManager<List<Contact>> dbObj = new FileManager<List<Contact>>();
Contact conobj = new Contact();
List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>()
{
new Contact(){ Name="abc", Age=14, Date=new DateTime(2017,05,12),         City="sss"},
};
lstContact.Add(conobj);
dbObj.SaveFile(lstContact);
dbObj.LoadFile();
Program callobj = new Program();
callobj.Menu();
Console.ReadLine();
}
public void Menu()
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter your Choice:");
Console.WriteLine("1. Edit Users");
    try
        {
            int i = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        System.Console.WriteLine("You have selected to Edit Users");
                        Program.Edit();
                        break;
                    }
           }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    public static Contact Edit()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Your Name: ");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter Your Age:");
        byte Age = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Your Date Of Birth in MM-DD-YYYY Format:");
        DateTime DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Your City : ");
        string City = Console.ReadLine();
        Contact newobj = new Contact(0, Name, Age, DOB, City);

        Console.WriteLine("Your name is : " + newobj.Name.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Your Age is : " +         Convert.ToInt32(newobj.Age).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Your DOB is : " +     newobj.Date.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("Your City is : " + newobj.City.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Type Y to edit the userdata and N to return back to the MENU");
        bool confirmed = false;
        string Key;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your option: ");
            Key = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered, " + Key + " as your response!");

            ConsoleKey response;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Are you sure you want to edit? [y/n] ");
                response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
                if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    Console.WriteLine();

            } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);

            confirmed = response == ConsoleKey.Y;
        } while (!confirmed);
        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0}!", Key);
        Contact editobj = new Contact(0, Name, Age, DOB, City);
        return editobj;
    }
}
```

}

I want to take input of data from user and then I want to edit that data. Can it be done? I mean is it possible to edit the data and then return the modified data in the console application? Also, I think that maybe I can create another object below and then after editing is done, I can return the new object which will override the previously created object. Am I right? I hope I have asked the right question. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, it can be done but it's not clear what you are want. Give us an example of the input and the output you want. And what you have tried so far

Comment: I want Name, age, city, DateOfBirth from the user. Then I have written code to print that data. Now I want to edit this same data, modify it and print that modified data.

Comment: And how do you want to edit or modify it. Give us an example with example data ;)

Comment: Do you measn something like [LineEditor](https://github.com/mono/LineEditor)?